# Can't install or create environment in conda

Tags: python, json, anaconda, conda

Every time I try to install a package or create an environment with `conda` appears, a message like this:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): / DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): conda.anaconda.org:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
- DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /conda-forge/osx-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
\ DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/osx-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://conda.anaconda.org:443 "GET /conda-forge/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

For example:

To create an environment called `env3:

```
conda create -n env3 -vv
```

Appears:

```
DEBUG conda.gateways.logging:set_verbosity(218): verbosity set to 2
DEBUG conda.core.solve:solve_final_state(297): solving prefix /home/nayelilv/anaconda3/envs/env3
  specs_to_remove: frozenset()
  specs_to_add: frozenset()
  prune: Null
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __archspec
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __osx
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __unix
done
Solving environment: ...working... DEBUG conda.resolve:get_reduced_index(673): Retrieving packages for: 
DEBUG conda.core.solve:_add_specs(823): specs_map with targets: {'__archspec': MatchSpec("__archspec"), '__osx': MatchSpec("__osx"), '__unix': MatchSpec("__unix")}
DEBUG conda.resolve:get_reduced_index(673): Retrieving packages for: 
  - __archspec
  - __osx
  - __unix
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __unix
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __osx
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __archspec
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(613): Invoking SAT with clause count: 2
DEBUG conda.resolve:_get_sat_solver_cls(79): Using SAT solver interface 'pycosat'.
DEBUG conda.resolve:gen_clauses(1061): gen_clauses returning with clause count: 9
DEBUG conda.resolve:generate_spec_constraints(1069): generate_spec_constraints returning with clause count: 9
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(613): Invoking SAT with clause count: 12
DEBUG conda.resolve:bad_installed(1282): Checking if the current environment is consistent
DEBUG conda.core.solve:_find_inconsistent_packages(646): inconsistent precs: None
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __unix
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __osx
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __archspec
DEBUG conda.resolve:gen_clauses(1061): gen_clauses returning with clause count: 9
DEBUG conda.resolve:generate_spec_constraints(1069): generate_spec_constraints returning with clause count: 9
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(613): Invoking SAT with clause count: 12
DEBUG conda.core.solve:_run_sat(1042): final specs to add: 
  - __archspec
  - __osx
  - __unix
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1439): Solving for: 
  - 0: __osx target=None optional=False
  - 1: __archspec target=None optional=False
  - 2: __unix target=None optional=False
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1445): Solve: Getting reduced index of compliant packages
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1477): Solve: determining satisfiability
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __unix
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __osx
DEBUG conda.resolve:__init__(132): restricting to unmanageable packages: __archspec
DEBUG conda.resolve:gen_clauses(1061): gen_clauses returning with clause count: 9
DEBUG conda.resolve:generate_spec_constraints(1069): generate_spec_constraints returning with clause count: 9
DEBUG conda.common._logic:_run_sat(613): Invoking SAT with clause count: 12
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1531): Requested specs: 
  - __archspec
  - __osx
  - __unix
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1532): Optional specs: 
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1533): All other specs: 
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1534): missing specs: 
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1537): Solve: minimize removed packages
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1544): Solve: maximize versions of requested packages
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1550): Initial package channel/version metric: 0/0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1553): Solve: minimize track_feature count
DEBUG conda.resolve:generate_feature_count(1081): generate_feature_count returning with clause count: 12
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1556): Track feature count: 0
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1567): Package misfeature count: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1570): Solve: maximize build numbers of requested packages
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1572): Initial package build metric: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1575): Solve: prefer arch over noarch for requested packages
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1577): Noarch metric: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1581): Solve: minimize number of optional installations
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1584): Optional package install metric: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1587): Solve: minimize number of necessary upgrades
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1590): Dependency update count: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1593): Solve: maximize versions and builds of indirect dependencies.  Prefer arch over noarch where equivalent.
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1602): Additional package channel/version/build/noarch metrics: 0/0/0/0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1611): Solve: prune unnecessary packages
DEBUG conda.common._logic:minimize(673): Empty objective, trivial solution
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1614): Weak dependency count: 0
DEBUG conda.resolve:solve(1622): Looking for alternate solutions
done
DEBUG conda.core.solve:solve_final_state(423): solved prefix /home/nayelilv/anaconda3/envs/env3
  solved_linked_dists:
    

DEBUG conda.core.prefix_data:_load_single_record(190): loading prefix record /home/nayelilv/anaconda3/conda-meta/jsonschema-4.17.3-py311h06a4308_0.json
DEBUG conda.core.prefix_data:_load_single_record(190): loading prefix record /home/nayelilv/anaconda3/conda-meta/libssh2-1.10.0-h37d81fd_2.json
DEBUG conda.core.prefix_data:_load_single_record(190): loading prefix record /home/nayelilv/anaconda3/conda-meta/param-1.13.0-py311h06a4308_0.json
DEBUG conda.core.prefix_data:_load_single_record(190): loading prefix record /home/nayelilv/anaconda3/conda-meta/bokeh-3.2.1-py311h92b7b1e_0.json 
DEBUG conda.core.prefix_data:_load_single_record(190): loading prefix record /home/nayelilv/anaconda3/conda-meta/jupyter_console-6.6.3-py311h06a4308_0.json
DEBUG conda.core.prefix_data:_load_single_record(190): loading prefix record /home/nayelilv/anaconda3/conda-meta/pycparser-2.21-pyhd3eb1b0_0.json
...

INFO conda.core.link:__init__(210): initializing UnlinkLinkTransaction with
  target_prefix: /home/nayelilv/anaconda3/envs/env3
  unlink_precs:
    
  link_precs:
    

DEBUG conda.core.package_cache_data:__init__(717): instantiating ProgressiveFetchExtract with
```

To install a package from `conda`, the message appears again and it get frozen:

```
conda install -c conda-forge mamba
```

Again:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): ...working... DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTPS connection (1): repo.anaconda.com:443
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/osx-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/osx-64/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://repo.anaconda.com:443 "GET /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json HTTP/1.1" 304 0
done
Solving environment: unsuccessful initial attempt using frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed
```

I already tried:

- Uninstall and reinstall Anaconda, the version of conda is `23.7.2`.
- Several posts with similar issue like: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63317348/why-is-my-connection-to-repo-anacoda-com-failing) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285584/unable-to-install-a-package-in-conda-not-found) and [this](https://community.anaconda.cloud/t/after-each-new-environment-i-need-to-run-conda-clean-why/57229/2) and [this](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/issues/4539) no one worked for me.

I'm using Ubuntu 23.04.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? The environment creation looks fine. The last one looks like not waiting long enough (Anaconda **base** is often difficult to install extra packages into). Could you show examples without the `-vv` flags first? - the DEBUG info isn't adding anything here.

Comment: yes it is the first chunk

Comment: There is no error shown there - just debugging messages being printed. The HTTP codes are normal (304: unmodified; 200: OK). Please show one complete example of: a command run, the resulting behavior, and the expected behavior.

Comment: The resulting behavior is that I can't install anything in conda base env or in any environment. The expected behavior is first that I can install packages and second that I can create environments without that message. I am very used to  Anaconda, and those messages aren't normal, and I don't know how to fix it. In the post are the commands that I ran; I don't know if you are familiar with conda/ Anaconda and virtual envs... because I don't know which other information could be useful.

Comment: Did your configuration get changed to turn up the verbosity? Check `conda config --show verbosity`. There is nothing inherently wrong with any of the messages shown. Please add some direct evidence here to demonstrate that an environment isn't created (show `conda env list` before and after) or a package isn't installed (show `conda list` before and after). Please edit the post with this information.

Comment: Also, mixing Conda Forge packages with Anaconda **base** is not recommended and often leads to infinite solves or incompatibilities. If you want Mamba, start from a minimal **base** environment, like Mambaforge.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Anaconda and installed [mamba](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba), and now I can work. It isn't a solution *per se*, but it could be a good option if you had the same problems as me.